# How to draw only outer edges on a 3D shape

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, math, matplotlib-3d

I am working on a physics simulator that takes in a bunch of mass coordinates and applies spring forces to each mass. I'm trying to draw only outer edges of the 3D shape. In a simple case, the shape is at first a cube, and then because of gravity and spring forces the cube deforms. I'm sort of able to draw the outer edges on the non-deformed cube, but only as far as this:
[image]

I am still missing most of the edges and as soon as deformation begins I lose all the edges. My code that's being used to draw these edges is as follows:

```
shaded_plotting = []
        m1 = mass_vertices[0]
        j = 0
        for i in range(len(mass_vertices)):
            for j in range(1, len(mass_vertices)):
                m2 = mass_vertices[j]
                if (m1[0] != m2[0] and m1[1] == m2[1] and m1[2] == m2[2]) or \
                        (m1[0] == m2[0] and m1[1] != m2[1] and m1[2] == m2[2]) or \
                        (m1[0] == m2[0] and m1[1] == m2[1] and m1[2] != m2[2]):
                    if (list(m2), list(m1)) not in shaded_plotting:
                        shaded_plotting.append((list(m1), list(m2)))
            m1 = mass_vertices[j]
        shaded_plotting = np.array(shaded_plotting)
        shaded_plotting.shape = (len(shaded_plotting) * 2, 3)
        print(shaded_plotting)
        return M, S, shaded_plotting
```

I compare two points, and if there is only one different coordinate (x, y, or z), I draw a line between the two points and back to my beginning point. `mass_vertices` is my coordinates for the cube. Then this code is run again when the coordinates change (when deformations through gravity or spring forces take place).

Of course, as soon as various deformations happen, the above code is completely useless, as points will no longer at any time have only one different coordinate to another point. Mostly, I just don't see how I can a) simplify the code so the lines aren't drawn so often, and b) rewrite the code so that it would still only draw 12 edge lines for any arbitrary shape.

I have some ideas that might work, but I don't have too much of an idea on how to implement them. I think if I kept track of each mass and labeled it somehow, I would be able to keep the lines between each mass better.

I am able to draw the cube *and its deformations* with lines connecting every point, but it's much harder to see what's going on in that case. The cube looks like this when all lines are shown:
[image]

And the code for this is as follows:

```
class Mass:
    def __init__(self, m, rho, v, a):
        self.m = m
        self.rho = rho
        self.v = v
        self.a = a


class Spring:
    def __init__(self, k, L_0, L, m1, m2):
        self.k = k
        self.L_0 = L_0
        self.L = L
        self.m1 = m1
        self.m2 = m2 

   
M = []
S = []
for_plotting_S = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(mass_vertices)):
    M.append(Mass(m, mass_vertices[i], v, a))
for i in range(len(mass_vertices)):
    for j in range(1, len(mass_vertices)):
        m1 = M[i].rho
        m2 = M[j].rho
        original_m1 = Masses[i].rho
        original_m2 = Masses[j].rho
        L = np.linalg.norm(m1 - m2)
        L0 = np.linalg.norm(original_m1 - original_m2)
        if L != 0 and ((list(m2), list(m1)) not in for_plotting_S):
            S.append(Spring(k[count], L0, L, m1, m2))
            for_plotting_S.append((list(m1), list(m2)))
            count += 1
for_plotting_S = np.array(for_plotting_S)
for_plotting_S.shape = (len(for_plotting_S) * 2, 3)
            for_plotting_S.shape = (len(for_plotting_S) * 2, 3)
```

I am not very well versed in classes, so I am pretty certain that the class initialization above could be better utilized.

Comment: One idea is to find the convex hull of the points and draw the edges of that. A web search will find some well-known algorithms for that.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was sort of exactly what I was looking for, and although I was unable to implement it exactly, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is a deformed cube but once you have the vertices of a convex polyhedron, you can get and plot its edges as follows.

To get the convex hull and its edges, use **pycddlib** (the **cdd** library):

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cdd as pcdd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# vertices
points= np.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [4,0,0],
    [4,4,0],
    [0,4,0],
    [0,0,4],
    [4,0,4],
    [4,4,4],
    [0,4,4]
])

# to get the convex hull with cdd, one has to prepend a column of ones
vertices = np.hstack((np.ones((8,1)), points))

# do the polyhedron
mat = pcdd.Matrix(vertices, linear=False, number_type="fraction") 
mat.rep_type = pcdd.RepType.GENERATOR
poly = pcdd.Polyhedron(mat)

# get the adjacent vertices of each vertex
adjacencies = [list(x) for x in poly.get_input_adjacency()]

# store the edges in a matrix (giving the indices of the points)
edges = []
for i,indices in enumerate(adjacencies[:-1]):
    indices = list(filter(lambda x: x>i, indices))
    l = len(indices)
    col1 = np.full((l, 1), i)
    indices = np.reshape(indices, (l, 1))
    edges = edges.append(np.hstack((col1, indices)))
Edges = np.vstack(tuple(edges))

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

start = points[Edges[:,0]]
end = points[Edges[:,1]]

for i in range(12):
    ax.plot(
        [start[i,0], end[i,0]], 
        [start[i,1], end[i,1]], 
        [start[i,2], end[i,2]],
        "blue"
    )

ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")

ax.set_xlim3d(-1,5)
ax.set_ylim3d(-1,5)
ax.set_zlim3d(-1,5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually found your answer to a similar question yesterday, so I already tried to implement this, but this seemed to not work for my purposes. I will start over with this project soon enough though, and I will try to implement it so that something like this should work.